# Solving $T(n) = T(n/2) + T(n/3) + n$

Tags: algorithms, recurrence-relations, substitution

Show that the solution to the recurrence relation

> $$T(n) = n \;\;\;\;\text{ for }\; n=1,2$$
> $$T(n) = T(n/2) + T(n/3) + n \;\;\;\;\text{ for }\; n > 2$$

is $O(n)$ using substitution.

$$T(n) \leq c\cdot n - d$$
$$T(n) = \frac{c\cdot n}{2} - d + \frac{c\cdot n}{3} - d + n $$
$$T(n) = 5c\cdot n + 6n - 2d$$

I get stuck here. Any help is appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: The last line should be `T(n) <= 5cn/6 + 6n/6 - 2d`?

Comment: and then factor to get $T(n) = n/6(5c + 6) - 2d = O(n)$

Comment: Assume $T(n) \leq \alpha n$ for some fixed $\alpha > 0$ (without a constant term) and induct on $n$. Choose a value of $\alpha$ that makes the proof easiest.